# Can you make Video variants, transformations of video, with ActiveStorage?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, rails-activestorage

ActiveStorage seems to be mostly focused on images. While it does offer "preview" support to [get a thumbnail from a video](https://edgeguides.rubyonrails.org/active_storage_overview.html#previewing-files) -- what about "variants"?

With images, maybe it's uploaded as a JPG, but I can use the [variants feature](https://edgeguides.rubyonrails.org/active_storage_overview.html#transforming-images) to convert to a PNG, and/or resize it, whatever.

But what if I want to do something similar with videos? Let's say the video was uploaded as an mp4, but I want to transform it into [webm](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/WebM), or vice versa, or downsample it, or whatever.

How would one do this if one wanted to use ActiveStorage to keep track of the original uploaded file?

Comment: Did you ever get anywhere with this?

Comment: @jrochkind have you made any progress in finding information about making video variants using ActiveStorage?

Comment: No. As far as I know it is not possible, using the ActiveStorage "preview" or "variants" features. You could of course just make your own model that has it's own attachment(s) with ActiveStorage, and just make what you want and attach them manually.

Comment: I found how to transcode a video before storing it, I haven't tried yet but it may be helpful to you/others: https://github.com/streamio/streamio-ffmpeg

Answer (score 0):

I needed something to convert quicktime (mov) files into mp4.

This works locally, but uses *way* too much memory in production to be useful.

Still, it seems to work, so may help you it you have a *lot* of RAM to spare.

[Example](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/71362583/transcoding-quicktime-to-mp4-causes-huge-memory-consumption-and-crashes-on-herok): for a ~4.4mb video, it uses >1GB RAM to transcode it!

```rb
# Transcoding quicktime to mp4
if post_params[:files][1].content_type == "video/quicktime"

  # Transcode
  require 'streamio-ffmpeg'
  movie = FFMPEG::Movie.new(post_params[:files][1].tempfile.path)

  # Write new movie
  require 'tempfile'
  tempfile = Tempfile.new(["", ".mp4"]) 
  movie.transcode(tempfile.path)

  # Update tempfile path in ActiveStorage
  post_params[:files][1].tempfile = tempfile

  # Update headers
  post_params[:files][1].headers = post_params[:files][1].headers.sub("\nContent-Type: video/quicktime", "\nContent-Type: video/mp4")

end
```

So what I intend to do is offload these workloads to AWS lambdas, which could be triggered to run when an new file arrives in ActiveStorage.

I will update if I get it working successfully.