# Transcoding quicktime (.MOV) to mp4 causes huge memory consumption and crashes on heroku?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, heroku, video, ffmpeg

Converting a ~4.4MB quicktime (.MOV) video to .mp4 locally works fine, but on heroku it consumes over 1GB of memory and crashes the server.

#### Steps to reproduce

1. Take [this](https://drive.google.com/file/d/1mCM_SWonBfAxL-ni2ksImB-31f37Nxm8/view?usp=sharing) video, place it in the root of a new or existing rails app.
2. Add `gem 'streamio-ffmpeg', '~> 3.0', '>= 3.0.2'` to your gemfile and bundle, push to heroku, bundle on heroku.
3. Run `heroku run rails c` to jump into the rails console and try to convert the movie:

```rb
require 'streamio-ffmpeg'

# Read video file
movie = FFMPEG::Movie.new("IMG_1459.MOV") 

# Transcode video and save as an mp4
movie.transcode("IMG_1459.mp4")
```

The last line runs for a while then crashes.

#### Error logs

Converting the ~4.4MB video appears to *consume over 1GB of memory* (!!)

```
2022-03-05T13:00:24.678737+00:00 heroku[web.1]: Process running mem=1076M(210.3%)
2022-03-05T13:00:24.689256+00:00 heroku[web.1]: Error R15 (Memory quota vastly exceeded)
2022-03-05T13:00:24.691853+00:00 heroku[web.1]: Stopping process with SIGKILL
2022-03-05T13:00:24.810891+00:00 heroku[router]: at=error code=H13 desc="Connection closed without response" method=POST path="/posts" host=secure-inlet-07449.herokuapp.com request_id=7cd160ea-b332-4965-ae3f-563696dd054b fwd="1.145.252.113" dyno=web.1 connect=0ms service=29610ms status=503 bytes=0 protocol=https
2022-03-05T13:00:25.025812+00:00 heroku[web.1]: Process exited with status 137
2022-03-05T13:00:25.121873+00:00 heroku[web.1]: State changed from up to crashed
```

The logs are from similar code in an actual app.

#### Update

I think I *seriously* underestimated how much RAM it would consume. (I had assumed I had a memory leak or some unclosed connection somehow triggering a loop or similar). But it may be true that this is simply an incredibly memory-intensive task, and therefore is a bad idea to try to run in the app itself, and should be instead offloaded to an external processes (e.g. EC2's or AWS Lambdas etc).